# Python Parse Variable Number

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I got 8 channels, while off they got value = 0, while on:

```
ch1 = 1
ch2 = 10
ch3 = 100
ch4 = 1000
ch5 = 10000
ch6 = 100000
ch7 = 1000000
ch8 = 10000000
```

But when I ask which channel is opened, the hardware gives me a sum like

```
111 or 10001000
```

Meaning the ch1,ch2 and ch3 | ch4 and ch8 are opened respectively

I want to parse it in a way I can write a json like file with each channels status like

```
{
   "ch1": "on",
   "ch2": "off",
   "ch1": "on"
}
```

How do I do it? Whats the correct approach?

Comment: ...so what are you asking, then?

Comment: how to do it! I got the string, now I need the JSON

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a code writing service you need to show what you have tried/what isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

def chan_values(num):
    """parses int into an array of True/False values for the channels"""
    channels = []

    while num > 0:
        channels.append(num%10==1)
        num /= 10

    channels += [False]*(8-len(channels))

    return channels

print chan_values(111)
print chan_values(10001000)
```

To use, just call the function with the number as the argument. It will return a list of True/False values that you can iterate through to see which channels are on or you can check channel 6 with chan_values()[5].

And now for the explanation… The first while loop parses the number into individual digits. If the digit is one, it will return `True`, if not it will return `False`. The second while loop pads the list with `False`s if the input number is not 8 digits long (such as 111).

**EDIT:**
Replaced the second while loop with a faster one liner (`channels += [False]*(8-len(channels))`). Note that the two ways achieve the same goal and are equivalent in terms of result.

Comment: PERFECT! I was trying with .split('1') but then realized it would be a huge chunk of code and I am concerned with run time as well. I gonna keep studying! thanks for your help!

Comment: @CESCO Happy I could help. Since I answered your question correctly, I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as correct (just click on the check next to it).

Comment: sorry but I aint got enough reputation @pzp1997